# Invalid Vdd is coming during mmc driver access

Tags: linux, kernel

I am getting invalid vdd while mmc driver access in linux boot up.
basically during mmc_power_up function, after executing __mmc_set_signal_voltage and before setting power mode to MMC_POWER_ON, sdhci_runtime_suspend_host is been called followed by mmc_rescan. Though there is power off sequence is mmc_rescan, when it comes back to mmc_power_up function, it makes directly power mode to MMC_POWER_UP and goes in mmc_set_ios and later it calls sdhci_set_power where the BUG is coming as invalid vdd. In sdhci_set_power, vdd is 0 and power mode is 2(power on). Hence the problem.

I am using yocto kernel version 3.14.55 and I can't upgrade it due to some limitations.

Anybody can help me what is the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: The support for old Linux kernel stops and 3.14 is too old. Try and use version >4.4. Let me know if you face any problems during setup of new kernel version.